# nginx can't fetch keys from memcahed

Tags: django, nginx, memcached

The problem is that nginx don't fetch memcached keys which are presents in memcached, this happens every time i requests link.

the memcached logs:

Nginx request with key "site-/links" to memcached faild: (but key data in memcached)

```
<31 new auto-negotiating client connection
31: Client using the ascii protocol
<31 get site-/links                  ### NO DATA SEND! but it in cache
>31 END
<31 connection closed.
```

Django requests with key "site-/links" fetch data with success

```
<31 get :1:mkey
>31 sending key :1:mkeys 0 4
mval

(dp1
.

>31 END
<31 get :1:site-/links
>31 sending key :1:site-/links         ###data send!
>31 END
<31 set :1:site-/links 0 300 5518
>31 STORED
<31 set :1:mkey 0 300 4
>31 STORED
<31 connection closed.
```

my nginx cfg for memcached:

```
location / {
default_type  "text/html; charset=utf-8";
set $memcached_key site-$uri;
    memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;
    error_page     404 502 = @django;

}

location @django {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/tmp/site.sock;
}
```

django middlware:

```
class NginxMemCacheMiddleWare(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        cacheIt = True
        theUrl = request.get_full_path()

        # if it's a GET then store it in the cache:
        if request.method != 'GET':
            cacheIt = False

        # loop on our CACHE_INGORE_REGEXPS and ignore
        # certain urls.
        for exp in settings.CACHE_IGNORE_REGEXPS:
            if re.match(exp,theUrl):
                cacheIt = False

        if cacheIt:
            key = '%s-%s' % (settings.CACHE_KEY_PREFIX,theUrl)
            #key = theUrl
            print "CACHE!"
            print key

            print "MKEY:",cache.get("mkey")
            print cache.get(key)
            cache.set(key,response.content)
            cache.set("mkey","mval")

        return response
```

So why nginx can't fetch data with the key which in memcached and always goes to django uwsgi?

Answer (score 0):

from your memcached logs, your nginx is doing:

```
get site-/links
```

while your django is doing:

```
get :1:site-/links
```

Note: those are not the same keys, the django one has `:1:` in front!
(the `:1:` is propably added automatically by django as a sort of namespace)

In other words change your ningx config to match the following `location`-block:

```
location / {
  default_type  "text/html; charset=utf-8";
  set $memcached_key :1:site-$uri;
  memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;
  error_page     404 502 = @django;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the same setup and this is a problem.

Django's cache uses generational caching and puts a prefix in the key generator.

What you have to do is ensure you `set` from `django.core.cache.cache._cache` <-- the internal  memcached bindings.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache._cache.set(...)
```

To make this work on local environments where I use `DummyCache`, I've subclassed `DummyCache` with a property `_cache` which returns itself.

PS: be prepared for ridiculous performance. I'm currently limited by outbound traffic cap of 100mbits.